# onClick doesn't work on custom created element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

***Greetings***

I have built a search and every time user types word it renders new checkboxes but new checkboxes don't work like they used to be none of the event listeners work on new checkboxes, when I'm clicking on checkboxes they just don't react, but in old ones, until search will render this they are working normally

```
      //search in checkbox data
      const checkOptions = (container, value, containerId) => {
        for (let i = 0; i < props.unique[containerId].length; i++) {
          let item = props.unique[containerId][i];
          if (
            props.unique[containerId][i] !== null &&
            props.unique[containerId][i].includes(value)
          ) {
            element = (
              <label
                        onClick={(e) => {e.stopPropagation(); ifAnyChecked(e);}} key={i}>
                        <input onClick={(e) => {tableSearch(e);}} type="checkbox" value={item ? item : "empty"}/>
                        {item && item.length > 28 ? (
                          handleCheckbox(item)
                        ) : (
                          <p>{item}</p>
                        )}
                      </label>
            );
            tempData += ReactDOMServer.renderToString(element);
          }
        }
        container.innerHTML = tempData;
      };
```

any idea what's happening?

Comment: Can you create ```codesandbox.io``` example of this problem.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-wozniak-tgdc3?file=/src/App.js here is codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `onChange` event instead of `onClick`? As far as I know, input type checkbox doesn't have such an event like `onClick`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox

Comment: no, it doesn't work, onClick works in render method so that is not a problem

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this problem when I was working with Vanilla JS whenever i render a new element then that element was not triggering my events. That was because they were generated on runtime so the event wasn't bound to that element. Now I think that thing is happening here as well. So I changed your code and put it inside a state now it is working. I hope I helped. Do let me know if this is not the solution that you were looking for but it solves your problem though

I put the html inside a state array then i mapped it out inside the `newCheckBox` div. I changed the input to controlled input with `fieldValue` state. Lastly i changed the new checkbox alert from `onClick={alert("doesn't goes in")}` to `onClick={() => alert("I think its working now right?")}`

Here is the complete code sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-sea-vedvh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: it's working on codesandbox but not in my code, and high amount of data makes search really slow so pushing in array will cost expensive

Comment: I don't think it will be expensive because react is smart that way and that's why it uses key's on components to render them. Also what you are doing is not recommended basically changing DOM outside react. You maybe can achieve what you are doing using ```React.createElement()``` and ```ReactDom.render``` but it will replace code everytime and you will need to make new logic to overcome that. Please refer the following answer. Also i would recommend you to make my codesandbox code work in your code then test it to see if there are any issues
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50900364/13556091